# list of dates and times sorted to rows by date in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spread sheet that looks like this

```
Emp.    date       time
1       5-13-13    8:00
1       5-13-13    12:00
1       5-13-13    12:30
1       5-13-13    15:00
2       5-13-13    8:00
2       5-13-13    12:00
3       5-13-13    8:00
3       5-13-13    12:00
3       5-13-13    12:30
3       5-13-13    15:00
1       5-14-13    8:00
1       5-14-13    12:00
1       5-14-13    12:30
```

and I would like to automatically convert it to something like this

```
Emp.    date       in    lunch1   lunch2    out
1       5-13-13    8:00  12:00    12:30     15:00 
2       5-13-13    8:00                     12:00
3       5-13-13    8:00  12:00    12:30     15:00
1       5-14-13    8:00  12:00    12:30     15:00
```

is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this often, turn on macro recorder. Copy your data to a new sheet, sort by date and Emp. Subtotal to count time for each change in Emp. In B6 insert `=B5`. Apply the following formulae to D6, D7, D8 and D9 respectively:

> =IF($C6=4,OFFSET($C6,-4,0),OFFSET($C6,-2,0))
>   =IF($C6=4,OFFSET($C6,-3,0),"")
>   =IF($C6=4,OFFSET($C6,-2,0),"")
>   =IF(OR($C6=2,$C6=4),OFFSET($C6,-1,0))

Filter to select if A contains "co" and date and formulae down as required. Turn filter off. Copy entire sheet and Paste Special Values over the top. Filter Emp. for does not contain `co` and delete all visible apart from headers. Remove filter and Subtotal with Remove All. Replace “ Count” with nothing, delete bottom row and time. Add headings. Format to suit.

Adjust references to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Add another column that specifies what the time means, i.e. in, out, lunch1, lunch2. Make sure each row has that detail. Then you can build a pivot table with a few clicks

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you insert two or more dummy rows above your data (so the first data row is at least row 4) then you can put the formula `=IF($A1=$A4, 3, IF($A2=$A4, 2, IF($A3=$A4, IF($A5=$A4, 1, 3), 0)))` into cell `D4` and drag/fill down, and it will evaluate to 0 for “in”, 1 for “lunch1”, 2 for “lunch2”, and 3 for “out”, as per Teylyn’s suggestion.  (You need the first data row to be at least row 4 so the formula can refer to cells three rows back without getting a `#REF!` error.)